# JQuery Accordion images side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm somewhat adept at writing html but, CSS and JS kind of confuse me.  I'm trying to learn so, hopefully, one of you Masters can help me out.  I am trying to place multiple images within a each panel of my JQuery Accordion.  Thus far, I've inserted two images in the 1st panel and they are "stacking" as opposed to appearing side by side.  Ideally, I would like to have 4 side by side images in each panel.  Below is a link to the JSFiddle I am using.

Again, I'm a little wet behind the ears with this stuff so, please try to be specific as possible in your response.

In the same project, I'm wondering if there is a way to add an icon to the Header bars. Lastly, looking for a way to have the panels all closed upon loading.  As it stands, the page loads with first panel open.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you for your time.

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Del087/CzE3q/981/

```
#accordion {
width:100%;
margin:10px auto;
border:1px solid black;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
-moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#accordion h2 {
cursor:pointer;
margin:0px 0px;
padding:7px 15px;
background-color:#ff6600;
font:bold 16px Petua One;
color:#ffffff;
text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#accordion .content {
background-color:#ffffff;
padding:10px 15px;
color:black;
height:150px;
}
#accordion h2.active {
background-color:#000000;
}`

<div id="accordion">
 <h2>League Scores</h2>

<div class="content"><a      href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/Association%20Logos/PAHL210210_zps694744b9.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Association%20Logos/PAHL210210_zps694744b9.png" height="100" width="100" border="0" alt=" photo PAHL210210_zps694744b9.png"/></a>
    <br><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Pittsburgh Amateur Hockey League</a>
    <br>Squirt</div>


        <div><a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/Association%20Logos/HPHL_zps31e66fcd.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Association%20Logos/HPHL_zps31e66fcd.png" width="100" height="100" border="0" alt=" photo HPHL_zps31e66fcd.png"/></a></div>
 <h2>League Standings</h2>

<div class="content">....</div>
 <h2>Tournament Scores</h2>

<div class="content">....</div>
 <h2>Tournament Standings</h2>

<div class="content">....</div>
```

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/CzE3q/982/) what you want???

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm looking for.  Thanks very much.  Now how can I "condense" a little bit or close the gap between images?  Again, thanks very much for your assistance.

Comment: sure..will help you...but could you please mark my answer as accepted if i add it...

Comment: Absolutely.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your CSS a little bit as follows

```
#accordion {
    width:100%;
    margin:10px auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#accordion h2 {
    clear: both;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0px 0px;
    padding:7px 15px;
    background-color:#ff6600;
    font:bold 16px Petua One;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#accordion .content {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    padding:10px 15px;
    color:black;
    height:150px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#accordion h2.active {
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

Here i've specified a width of 50% for the content div and floated them.And to clear the floats from the accordion, i added a `clear:both` to `#accordion h2`

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/CzE3q/982/)

Comment: Not stick together but, just looking for an "aesthetically pleasing" gap.  I want to add two more images to the right of these two so, I want to make sure they all fit.

Comment: ya sure..you can add any number of images..but dont forget to reduce the width of the content div..for eg: if you want to add 4 images then giv a width of 25% for content div..

Comment: Okay great!  Last thing would be that panel one is not completely closing.  What I mean is that when I click on "Panel 2", Panel 1 should completely close but, it seems the 2nd image is keeping it open, if that makes any sense.

Comment: See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/CzE3q/983/)..changed css and html a little bit..added one more div named content1..

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow so, I'm trying to find exactly where I do that.  Also, Panel 1 is working great, however, the same thing is occurring with Panel 2.  It is not closing all the way.

Comment: please click the tick symbol next to my answer and you can accept the answer as accepted..

Comment: Got it.  Again, thanks so much.  If I can get that 2nd panel to close completely, I'm good to go.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: It is closing completley..see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/CzE3q/984/)